# how to merge odd number line and even number line in vim?

Tags: regex, linux, vim

In order to merge the odd number line and the even number line in two methods.
One use command `:s`, the other use command `:g` and `:s`.
It's our homework and I could not get appropriate answer from the google.
And I had worked out the first one, which means I can solve it with command `:s`:

```
:%s/\(^.*$\)\n\(^.*$\)/\1 \2
```

And how could I use command `:d` and `:s` to solve it?

#### BEFORE:

```
 1 aa  
 2 bb  
 3 abc  
 4 abc  
 5 an apple  
 6 is a bug   
 7 mazic  
 8 homework!  
 9 try a time  
10 dodo
```

#### AFTER:

```
 1 aa bb  
 2 abc abc  
 3 an apple is a bug  
 4 mazic homework!  
 5 try a time dodo
```

---

---

---

thanks to everyone and I have leant about how to solve it before the lesson.hah
`:g/\(^.*$\)\n\(^.*$\)/s//\1 \2`

Comment: 1. If it's your homework, the solution was already shown to you by your teacher. Use your notes. 2. Your formatting is an abomination. 3. Learn Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is :
Move the cursor to the line number to which you want to append the next line and then type below command in normal mode.

```
:s/\n/ /
```

Another way is go to the particular line and press SHIFT+V and then type below command:

```
:'<,'>s/\n/, /
```

Note that when you are in visual mode and press : then :'<,'> will automatically get typed. You just need to type regex ahead of that.

In both the above commands, g is not needed as it will not do any impact because only one \n will be there for each line.

Comment: It is not just match two line one time,but all the text,and I think that g is used to first mark all the line,and then delete the \n in the odd one with s.But I do not know how to write it.

Comment: I am not sure about using g and s but, you can simply use this

:g/^/j

Comment: Right,I have got this command from google and they really work out but,my teacher ask me to use g and s...so puzzled..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `:substitute` here, there's a special command `:join`.

You can use the Ex command with `:global`, using `^` as the pattern to match all lines:

```
:global/^/join
```

Or use the shorter normal mode variant `J`:

```
:%normal! J
```